# MySQL Sub Query with Rand

Tags: mysql

I have a VIEW that uses a sub query. The query and results it produces are correct, but the statement is only working for the first row. The second row and onward are empty. It’s likely due to LIMIT and it’s position in the query, but I don’t know how to fix it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT id,badge, ( SELECT result FROM tab2
where (tab1.basic = tab2.basic or (tab1.basic <>'' and tab2.basic = ''))
and (tab1.advanced = tab2.advanced or (tab1.advanced <>'' and tab2.advanced = ''))
and tab1.type = tab2.type
ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) as col1
FROM tab1;
```

Edit:

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=582b7eaa34ad1f1c8db06b8a348690df

Comment: We won't know how to fix it either if you don't tell us what you're expecting

Comment: please make a full [mre] the query looks ok, besides if you randomize the order, there is no chance to have a deterministic result

Comment: @ Caius Jard, I was hoping would run the same query and return a random result. It works for the first row, just not the rows below it.

Comment: @nbk, I’ll create a fiddle and will update the post.

Comment: I created a Fiddle and it works. The only difference between the fiddle I created and my actual design is in the fiddle I used two tables, where my actual build uses a table and a VIEW. Could a VIEW used in a VIEW cause this behaviour? I’ll edit my post and add the current fiddle.